# Elementary OS Juno and Windows 10 dualboot time is wrong. RTC time is not changing to local

Tags: release-juno, dual-boot, time

I installed release Juno recently. I used to have Manjaro before. `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` worked perfectly in Manjaro. It is not working in EOS. I am dual-booting with Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please execute this in your terminal,

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

Do not worry if you see a warning after running `timedatectl`.

Comment: Yes I did do this. Does not work.

Comment: Well can you please [read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts), this has all the information you need.

Comment: Oh and one more thing, have you tried to fix this in GUI before getting hands dirty in terminal? And I suggest you read the Ubuntu help article thoroughly I linked in my comment, it shows all possible ways. Let me know the results.

Comment: Ok I booted into eOS again. The time is correct now. I didn't even change anything. Thanks Hasan anyway.

Comment: In that case let me ask you **did you reboot your computer after adjusting system clock?**